# what is the default ha-proxy load balance algorithm?

Tags: ubuntu, load-balancing, haproxy

When i was configuring a proxy server which is ha-proxy over Ubuntu server ,
i forgot to choose a balance option in the  *haproxy.cnf*  file ,but steal worked correctly, any one have an idea what algorithm is runing ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From official documentation of Haproxy 1.6:

> " The load balancing algorithm of a backend is set to roundrobin when
>   no other algorithm, mode nor option have been set. The algorithm may
>   only be set once for each backend."

Refer this link for details : https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4-balance